# Is compressing string before save on PostgresSQL worth anything?

Tags: php, postgresql, compression

We are storing encrypted file contents in a PostgresSQL database. We store a lot of them. For now we are not able to write this contents in any other place (like FTP or internal storage). Still our database is becoming bigger and bigger quite fast.

I already know that PostgreSQL is compressing string data by default, so my question is: is it worth to do string compression on the application side before inserting it into the database. Will this save any space?

Maybe you know how to tweak PostgreSQL or any other methods to save some space when storing files in a PostgreSQL table.

---

**My extended answer**

As I wanted to know more I did few experiments.

- I created source file with **20000 lines** where **1 line = 50000 random characters**.
- Created file where 1 line is compressed line from source file using `gzdeflate`
- I created table with one column and inserted each line as 1 row.
- Compared sizes

This are the results:

- source file - **~1GB**
- file with each line compressed - **4.45MB**
- column `text` `STORAGE EXTENDED` - table size **13MB**
- column `text` `STORAGE EXTERNAL` - table size **1MB** + toast **1027MB**
- column `bytea` with pre gzdeflated data - table size **5.2MB**

I would like to note that pre compressing and storing data as text with `STORAGE EXTENDED` is possible and result was **700kb** table size **BUT** pre compressed data contains characters out of most charset palette. Retrieving such data would be impossible.

**Conclusion:**

- If you prefer to store data as `text`, ~13MB per ~1GB content is very nice ratio.
- If you need better compression and you don't mind storing data as blob/bytea and creating additional scripts for managing inserted/retrieved data... well... consider if this few MB are worth it.
- Also remember: by default PostgreSQL is compressing strings `>2kb`. If your string has less than ~2000 characters you have to change this setting or compress data by yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html#STORAGE-TOAST-ONDISK) for details.

PostgreSQL's compression algorithm is fast, but not very good, so you can save space by compressing the data before you save them.

But then you should alter the table to use the `EXTERNAL` storage strategy for the column. Otherwise PostgreSQL will waste CPU cycles needlessly by compressing the already compressed values, only to realize they won't get smaller and storing them the way they were originally.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did more research to this topic which I shared under original question. Best regards!

Comment: I freely admit that I couldn't quite understand everything, but I suggest that you add it as an answer rather than to the question.